# Por que usar interface (repository) em .Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, interface, repository

Estou iniciando meus estudo em *.Net* e estou com uma dificuldade imensa de entender o porque usar interface no código. Na minha cabeça a controller já teria a funcionalidade de criar os métodos para as models.
Vi que normalmente o pessoal cria uma pasta *"Repository"* e nela coloca os contratos e etc. Mas não consigo de jeito nenhum entender o conceito.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

O controller vai garantir que os dados de solicitação sejam válidos e escolher qual exibição deve ser retornada. Não necessariamente o controller vai fazer acesso a dados ou conter regras de negócio, que podem estar em outros locais dependendo do padrão de projeto que você está utilizando. No DDD por exemplo, essas regras de negócio podem estar nos serviços (services).

Geralmente no padrão repository, vc cria a lógica de acesso a dados e quando a Action que está dentro do Controller for acionada na aplicação, ele vai receber os dados que forem recebidos desse repositório.

Answer (score -1):

Não é sobre .NET, é sobre boas práticas mesmo,você está delegando toda a responsabilidade para os controllers quando eles deveriam ter a finalidade de desempacotar sua request, [Repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) é um design pattern que vai lhe ajudar a desacoplar o acesso ao dados de sua aplicação, se você tiver que um dia trocar de banco ou alguma API você faria isso na repository, eu já trabalhei em projetos em que as aplicações inteiras quebravam o S do SOLID e eram um verdadeiro inferno para dar manutenção, se alguma lib parar de funcionar por exemplo, ai que sua dor de cabeça começa, sobre interfaces recomendo estudar programação orientada a objetos, estude SOLID e comece a estudar arquitetura de software e as coisas vão fazer mais sentido para você